# using dd with conv=sparse to punch zeros

Tags: linux, disk-image, dd, fat32

I am attempting to clone a disk partition to an image file using dd. I want to create the image without zeros to minimize the filesize, and on the other hand I do not want to pipe through gzip. The solution I found consists of writing zeros to a dummy file until the disk is full. The problem I am running into is this is a FAT32 filing system, so I am limited to making these dummy files 4.3GB. Tedious to say the least.

My question: If I have an already zero'd drive with a new partition table and freshly written data to the partition... would I be safe to skip the "filling the free space" step and just go right to running dd using conv=sparse? The entire drive had been zero'd out prior to partition creation, so I am confident that the free space should already be zeros.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but maybe you should check out the [partclone](http://partclone.org) utility, which seems to "understand" FAT32. It should therefore automatically "leave out" unused space and produce a smaller image than dd.

Comment: I'm not married to dd. It just seems to be quick and effective if used correctly. I will try partclone. I assume if its not a part of my already installed packages, I will obtain and test. Thank you for the timely response, friend!

Comment: ># partclone.fat32 -cs /dev/sdb1 -o /media/user0/5acf82c8-507a-479c-adac-a947fc7065d8/sdb1.fat32

done!
File system:  FAT32
Device size:  125.0 GB = 244197376 Blocks
Space in use:  39.9 GB = 77865216 Blocks
Free Space:    85.2 GB = 166332160 Blocks

I see how it calculates the free space... and I assume it does not image that portion of the partition?

Comment: Im noticing the output shows that the total blocks matches the size of the entire partition. "current block:   40730548, total block:  244197376, Complete:  16.68%". I'm hoping it will reach the in use block count and complete. I fear that I missed a switch or argument to exclude free space.

Comment: I see...  it is processing the entire partition and omitting the free space when it writes the image. The final file size was correct. Thank you Oliver for this wonderful solution!

Comment: Glad to know it worked! I have added my comment as an answer now.

Comment: I'm obviously new here... is there a way that I can give you a thumbs up, like, upvote, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to will unused space with zeroes, you could check out the [partclone](http://partclone.org) utility. This tool understands the FAT32 format (among others) and will automatically leave out unused space so your dump will be much smaller than if you do it with `dd`.